# Get item from json in PHP

Tags: php, json

How to get the "duration" value from the below json in PHP :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"6jI4SSPcXxEAc3i_1EQHOPi0Cvc/EGNSBh81ISlkeECbqD9xdh5C340\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"6jI4SSPcXxEAc3i_1EQHOPi0Cvc/yUebIRJfQ62Pq5XpRbqJHx7Xozo\"",
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT15M51S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "contentRating": {
     "ytRating": ""
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Tried many examples but either it results in object error or invalid index error ?

Comment: Show the PHP object, not the original JSON.

Comment: Once json_decoded, you can say `['items']['contentDetails']['duration']`

Comment: please post what u tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jsonObj  = json_decode($json);
$duration = $jsonObj->items[0]->contentDetails->duration;
```

or

```
$jsonArr  = json_decode($json, true);
$duration = $jsonArr['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'];
```

or in a loop:

```
$jsonArr  = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($jsonArr['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
```

Comment: Tested the first one and it works, thanks :).

Any ideas how to convert the parsed "ISO 8601" duration into seconds ?

Comment: have a look into this question :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721085/parse-and-create-iso-8601-date-and-time-intervals-like-pt15m-in-php

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :

```$interval = new DateInterval($duration);
$tseconds = (($interval->format('%h')*60)*60)+($interval->format('%i')*60)+$interval->format('%s');
echo $tseconds;```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"6jI4SSPcXxEAc3i_1EQHOPi0Cvc/EGNSBh81ISlkeECbqD9xdh5C340\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"6jI4SSPcXxEAc3i_1EQHOPi0Cvc/yUebIRJfQ62Pq5XpRbqJHx7Xozo\"",
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT15M51S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "contentRating": {
     "ytRating": ""
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

here in url video id is id of video please remember to change it

```
<?php
$url=file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoid?v=2");
$data = json_decode($url);

$duration = $data['items']['duration'];
echo $duration;
?>
```