# how to convert duration from ISO format PT1h30M to int duration basing on number of minutes in php?

Tags: php, duration

I want to convert a duration from ISO 8601 format to an integer by computing the number of minute in this duration. For exemple if I have  PT1h30M , I want to convert it to 90, because I need to store this inforamtion in my data base as integer (the number of minute). is there any function in PHP to do this?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721085/parse-and-create-iso-8601-date-and-time-intervals-like-pt15m-in-php

Comment: @justbaron thank you very much, effectively it answers my problem !! So if you want, make your answer in answer block and I will accept it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse and create ISO 8601 Date and time intervals, like PT15M in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721085/parse-and-create-iso-8601-date-and-time-intervals-like-pt15m-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few answers out there relating to conversion of ISO 8601 format.

Check out PHP 5.3+ [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

Also, [Parse and create ISO 8601 Date and time intervals, like PT15M in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721085/parse-and-create-iso-8601-date-and-time-intervals-like-pt15m-in-php)